# Pagination with AWS DynamoDB with PHP

Tags: php, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

Have someone any idea about Paginating the records from a table. Actually I want to create a paginate component in php with DynamoDb.

It seems like it is not possible to giving pagination like <first> <prev> 1,2,3,**4**,5... <next> <last>.

Because Dyanmodb just provide us LIMIT clause by which we can read certain no. of records and we can process next n records by LastEvaluatedKey. So if I want to jump directly to 5th page, How is it possible ?

As per my understanding we can't display page numbers into the pagination. The thing we can do is just read certain limit of records and provide the NEXT link to retrieve next n records.

Pagination is basic feature of any web application, How can we implement if migrating to cloud database like DynamoDb ?

Please provide your views and suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, there is no `OFFSET` in DynamoDB. But using only `Limit` and `LastEvaluatedKey`, i made this function:

```
public function scan($table, $filter = [], $select = null, $limit = 2)
{
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
    $options = [
        'TableName' => $table,
        'Count' => true,
    ];

    if (!empty($limit)) {
        $options['Limit'] = $limit;
    }

    if (!is_null($select)) {
        $options['Select'] = $select;
    }

    if (!empty($filter)) {
        $options['ScanFilter'] = $filter;
    }

    $results = $results = $this->_client->scan($options);

    while ($page > 0 && isset($results['LastEvaluatedKey'])) {
        $results = $results = $this->_client->scan($options);
        $options['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $results['LastEvaluatedKey'];
        $page--;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

`$this->_client` refers to DynamoDb client object.
Basically i loop through all entries with `LastEvaluatedKey` till i reach needed page.
To get total entries in table, call `$this->scan($this->tableName(), [], null, null)['Count'];` (that is - without any search criteria and without pagination, just as in normal pagination function).

Comment: this, without heavy caching, is going to be pretty terrible for performance for any page other then the first few

Comment: @MikeDinescu Yes, I know. Any better solution?

Comment: No, not really; I am not saying there is a better solution just throwing a caveat out there; the only improvement I can think of would be to make sure to cache the results (or at least the `LastEvaluatedKey`s so that subsequent calls don't incur the penalty of scanning each time)

Comment: @MikeDinescu Why cache `LastEvaluatedKey` if it's always changing in next iteration?

Comment: I started to add a comment but ran out of space so turned it into an answer to complement yours instead..

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Justinas' answer, Dynamo will have pretty horrible performance for pagination if random access (ie. jump to an arbitrary page) is desired. However, if you only do next page and previous page, you could pass around the `LastEvaluatedKey` and keep the overhead due to scanning to a minimum.

As stated in the comments, you should definitely cache the results as much as possible. At a minimum, the `LastEvaluatedKey` results could be cached so that they don't need to be recomputed for each paging request when users page through the results. Here's an example of what I mean:

Say you have a table that has a schema like this, where `CommentID` is the hash-key.

```
 CommentID | Author | Comment | ...
-----------+--------+---------+------------
    1      | Joe    | Foo     | ...
    2      | Joe    | Bar     | ...
    3      | John   | Baz     | ...
    4      | Joe    | FooBar  | ...
    5      | Jane   | BooBaz  | ...
    6      | Joesie | Blah    | ...
    7      | Johnny | Blahaha | ...
```

When you start paging, say you request 3 comments per page, you will get the first page results and the `LastEvaluatedKey = 3`; Then if you make a second scan request, for page 2, using `ExclusiveStartKey=3` you will get `LastEvaluatedKey = 6`; To get page 3 you would make another scan using `LastEvaluatedKey = 6`.. and so on.

You can see that without any kind of caching, to get Page 3 you are performing three scans (two of which would have been repeated if you also requested pages 1 and two prior to page 3). So, my proposed optimization is to store the corresponding keys for each page. You would end up with a map like this:

```
 Page | Hash-Key
------+----------
   1  |   null
   2  |     3
   3  |     6
  ..  |    ...
```

And the values would get filled out as you page through results. Now, when a user wants page 3, all you have to do is one scan, using `6` as the `ExclusiveStartKey`.

Of course you would need a look-up table like this for each page size, and the table would only be accurate until new rows get added (or removed). That said, if you have lots of requests the extra memory needed to store the paging cache would be well worth it. All is left then is to set a reasonable expiration for your paging cache, depending on how often new data is added (or removed) in your table..

Comment: What if comments get deleted, you have to now update a lot of your pagination index number key, not a good solution at all. I'm sure deletion would be a prime requirement.

Comment: @P.Prasad - not sure what you mean, but generally when you're paging through results you'd expect to be paginating through what would be a snapshot of sorts - deletions, much like inserts would be reflected in results on subsequent pagination requests eventually; depending on the frequency of deletes and inserts you would tweak the TTL of the cache, or even invalidate your cache

Comment: If item number 4,5,6 are deleted, all the entries in your page key map starting from page 2 will have to be modified such that their values are incremented by 3. This operation itself is resource intensive.

Comment: @P.Prasad - I think you misunderstood how the ExclusiveStartKey works and what I was proposing; you'd cache the values but never update them - if you feel like deletes and inserts occur too frequent;y then you can either not cache or invalidate the cache but you'd never adjust the keys