# DynamoDB; Fetch all data in a table - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

I found some help in how to get this done via the answer linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443683/pagination-with-aws-dynamodb-with-php/32133276#32133276).
But it doesn't fit my use case.
My goal is to fetch all records in a DynamoDB Table (usernames and emails). Looking through doc I have to use LastEvaluatedKey or ExclusiveStartKey to implement pagination. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will able to get all records from DynamoDB Table.

```
function scanAllData($table,$limit){

  $result = $this->getClientdb()->scan(array(
        'TableName' => $table,
        'Limit' => $limit,
        'Select' => 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES'                
     ),
    array('limit' => $limit),
  );
    return $result['Items'];
}
```

You can call this function like this. for example you have 'users' table and columns are `usernames` and `emails`

```
$getobj = $this->scanAllData('users','10');

foreach($getobj as $cols){

   echo $cols['usernames']['S'];
   echo $cols['emails']['S'];    

}
```

Comment: What if the records fetched are more than 1MB? Do you not need to implement pagination?

Comment: for pagination use jquery datatable and manage the pagination. Its responsive and advance feature.

Comment: When i say pagination I don't mean website pagination. Based on your code if my table contains 1 million records will the code echo all 1 million?

Comment: Yes good question. Now check i update my answer that will utilize limit on the dynamodb record.

Comment: I don't want to implement limit. I want to fetch all. Will your original answer fetch all?

Comment: @moh.ABK we use limit when we implement pagination do you know? we fix the value how much record we get on each page...

Comment: -1. This will **not** get you all the items in a table. You need to use [`ExclusiveStartKey`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ExclusiveStartKey) and [`LastEvaluatedKey`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-response-LastEvaluatedKey) for paginating through the records. If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size limit (currently 1 MB) you **need to make multiple scan requests**. You also need to be clear about what you call a `Query` vs a `Scan`.

Comment: but in this you can call the function more than one time on each page generate new request for record limit.

Comment: [`Limit`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Limit) is used to limit the amount of items to check before returning results. It is useful when you want to limit how much read capacity you consume. It has no way to generate an offset into your data.

Comment: @mkobit Can you please provide me with an example of implementing those 2 keys?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but here is a Java 8 example ran against [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) with a dependency on `compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.10.20'`. This shows how `Limit` (mostly, it doesn't show how filters effect the returned items), `LastEvaluatedKey`, and `ExclusiveStartKey` work. You can see how the parameters are set, and compare it to the PHP example:

```java
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.Tables;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import java.util.Map;

public class ScanExample {

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "test_table";
    private static final String HASH_ATTR_NAME = "hash";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secret");
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials);
        dynamoDBClient.setEndpoint("http://localhost:4000");

        if (Tables.doesTableExist(dynamoDBClient, TABLE_NAME)) {
            dynamoDBClient.deleteTable(TABLE_NAME);
        }

        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest();
        createTableRequest.setTableName(TABLE_NAME);
        createTableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(50l, 50l));

        createTableRequest.withKeySchema(
                ImmutableList.of(new KeySchemaElement(HASH_ATTR_NAME, KeyType.HASH)))
                .withAttributeDefinitions(ImmutableList.of(
                                new AttributeDefinition(HASH_ATTR_NAME, ScalarAttributeType.N))
                );

        dynamoDBClient.createTable(createTableRequest);
        Tables.awaitTableToBecomeActive(dynamoDBClient, TABLE_NAME);

        final Table table = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient).getTable(TABLE_NAME);
        createItems(table, 8);

        final int limit = 3;
        performScan(dynamoDBClient, limit);
    }

    private static void performScan(final AmazonDynamoDB client, final int limit) {
        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest(TABLE_NAME)
                .withLimit(limit);

        Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = null;
        do {
            final ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);
            System.out.println("With exclusiveStartKey=" + exclusiveStartKey);
            scanResult.getItems().forEach(System.out::println);
            exclusiveStartKey = scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();
            System.out.println("Result lastEvaluatedKey=" + exclusiveStartKey);
            // Reusing same request object, just setting the start key
            scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
            System.out.println();
        } while(exclusiveStartKey != null);
    }

    private static void createItems(final Table table, final int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            table.putItem(new Item().withNumber(HASH_ATTR_NAME, i));
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
With exclusiveStartKey=null
{hash={N: 2,}}
{hash={N: 1,}}
{hash={N: 3,}}
Result lastEvaluatedKey={hash={N: 3,}}

With exclusiveStartKey={hash={N: 3,}}
{hash={N: 5,}}
{hash={N: 7,}}
{hash={N: 0,}}
Result lastEvaluatedKey={hash={N: 0,}}

With exclusiveStartKey={hash={N: 0,}}
{hash={N: 6,}}
{hash={N: 4,}}
Result lastEvaluatedKey=null
```