# How to implement dynamodb pagination from last page page to 1st page?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I am implementing dynamo db pagination using PHP.

All is working fine if want to paginate from 1st to 2nd page, but if I want to go from 3rd to 1st page, I am not getting anywhere. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please share code samples of what you have so far and an error or description of unwanted behaviour in the failing case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)? The way paging works is by using the `LastEvaluatedKey` to make another request that starts at that key and moves in the direction specified by the `ScanIndexForward` attribute. So, you can only move backwards or forwards from a specific point in the table, and can't jump around.

I'm guessing here, but I think that this question might address your potential use case: [Pagination with AWS DynamoDB with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443683/pagination-with-aws-dynamodb-with-php).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the first page, simply make a new query.

In general though, you cannot use the API to iterate "backwards". If you have a small dataset,  you could save all the values locally and do your own iteration in any order you want.